# How to override the SerializeDateTime method of c# javascriptserializer class?

Tags: c#, .net, javascriptserializer

`SerializeDateTime` method returns datetime in milliseconds. I want him to turn to microseconds. `SerializeDateTime` method as follows:

```
private static void SerializeDateTime(DateTime datetime, StringBuilder sb, JavaScriptSerializer.SerializationFormat serializationFormat)
{
  if (serializationFormat == JavaScriptSerializer.SerializationFormat.JSON)
  {
    sb.Append("\"\\/Date(");
    sb.Append((datetime.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - JavaScriptSerializer.DatetimeMinTimeTicks) / 10000L);
    sb.Append(")\\/\"");
  }
  else
  {
    sb.Append("new Date(");
    sb.Append((datetime.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - JavaScriptSerializer.DatetimeMinTimeTicks) / 10000L);
    sb.Append(")");
  }
}
```

I want to override this method as follows.

```
private static void SerializeDateTime(DateTime datetime, StringBuilder sb, JavaScriptSerializer.SerializationFormat serializationFormat)
{
  if (serializationFormat == JavaScriptSerializer.SerializationFormat.JSON)
  {
    sb.Append("\"\\/Date(");
    sb.Append((datetime.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - JavaScriptSerializer.DatetimeMinTimeTicks));
    sb.Append(")\\/\"");
  }
  else
  {
    sb.Append("new Date(");
    sb.Append((datetime.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - JavaScriptSerializer.DatetimeMinTimeTicks));
    sb.Append(")");
  }
}
```

I do not know how to do it. How else can we come up with a solution?
Newtonsoft serializer cannot serialize my model when I want to try. If it worked, maybe I could set it up with dateformat.

Answer (score 0):

The method in question is not marked as [`virtual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual). It cannot be overridden.

Why not just create your own method in a static class?

```
public static CustomSerializer
{
    public static void SerializeDateTime(...) {
         //your implementation
    }
}
```